# Meaning of $M(n)=O\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}\right)$

Tags: asymptotics, riemann-hypothesis, mobius-function

I am trying to fully understand the implications of $M(n)=O\left(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}\right)$, where $M(n)$ is [Mertens function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function), being equivalent to Riemann Hypothesis.

(i) Is the equivalence biconditional? Why?

(ii) What is the meaning of $\epsilon$ and how big can it be? For instance, say $M(n)=O\left(\sqrt{n} \cdot \log\log(n)^{\theta}\right)$, where $\theta$ is unbounded. Is this still equivalent to $M(n)=O\left(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}\right)$? And what if $\left |M(n)\right | \sim \frac{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}{2\log(n)}$, where we have that $\frac{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}{2\log(n)}$ grows slightly faster than $\sqrt{n}\cdot \log\log(n)$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{n^{\frac{3}{4}}}{2\log(n)}}{\sqrt{n}\cdot \log\log(n)} = \infty$? Is this still equivalent to $M(n)=O\left(n^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon}\right)$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My assumption (but I am not quite in the context of the Mertens function) is that the expression "$f(n)=O(n^{1/2+\varepsilon})$" is just a shorthand for "for any $\varepsilon>0$ one has $|f(n)|\leq C_{\varepsilon}\cdot n^{1/2+\varepsilon}$". The point is then that $C_{\varepsilon}$ is independent of $n$ but may depend on $n$ (and it will unless we have something like $f(n)=O(n^{1/2})$).

Comment: @richrow thanks for your comment. When you say "is independent of $n$ but may depend on $n$", do you mean "is independent of $n$ but may depend on $\epsilon$", or "is independent of $\epsilon$ but may depend on $n$"?

Comment: Sory, yes, I meant $C_{\varepsilon}$ may depend on $\varepsilon>0$ but independent of $n$ (as hte notation suggests). E. g. $n^{1/2}\cdot\log n=O(n^{1/2+\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, but one cannot choose a universal constant for all $n$ and $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: @richrow thanks! So, how would you answer to the examples I have posed? I still think I am not able to answer to them. Feel free to post it as an answer if you want!